# Puedo hacer una macro con el explorador EDGE

Tags: excel, vba, edge

Amigos una consulta:
Tengo una macro en vba excel para hacer raspado de datos, la cual me está funcionando a la perfección. El problema radica en que este navegador ya es obsoleto y me da problemas en el cargue de la información. Quisiera saber si el código Vba utilizado para trabajar con el navegador "Internet Explorer" sirve también para el navegador "EDGE". O sólo sirve para trabajar en el Explorer.

```
Sub consultaDNP_enPrueba()
Dim IE, nom, ape1, gru, mun, fecenc, dep, desc, feccon As Object
Dim Totalregistros, j, fila As Integer
Dim doc, tipdoc As String
Totalregistros = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A3:A50"))
Dim pagina As HTMLDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'crea el explorador de internet
IE.navigate "https://reportes.gov.co/sisb_consulta"
On Error Resume Next
IE.Visible = True
Set pagina = IE.document 'la pagina cargada la almacenamos en una variable
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set pagina = IE.document
    Do While IE.Busy
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
     DoEvents
    Loop

x = 3
For j = 1 To Totalregistros ' total registro a consultar
    tipdoc = Hoja1.Cells(x, 1) ' se almacena el primer dato en la variable
    doc = Hoja1.Cells(x, 2) ' se almacena el segundo datos el variable
    IE.document.all.Item("TipoID").Value = tipdoc 'envio el primer datos a la página web
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) ' se espera que cargue
    IE.document.all.Item("documento").Value = doc 'se inserta el segundo dato en la casilla de la web
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    IE.document.all.Item("botonenvio").Click ' hacemos click en el boton
    Application.StatusBar = "Consulta...# " & j & " de " & Totalregistros
    
    If pagina.getElementsByClassName("campo1 pt-1 pl-2 font-weight-bold")(0).innerText = "" Then
      Range("K" & x).Value = "Sin datos"
      
      x = x + 1
    Else
    'EXTRAEMOS LA INFORMACION
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Set nom = IE.getElementsByClassName("campo1 pt-1 pl-2 font-weight-bold")(0) 'extraemos el valor de la posicion (0) de la tabla y lo almacenamos en la variable
    Range("C" & x).Value = nom.innerText 'insertamos el valor de la variable en la celda de la hoja excel
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Set apel = IE.getElementsByClassName("campo1 pt-1 pl-2 font-weight-bold")(1)
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Range("D" & x).Value = apel.innerText
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
       
    x = x + 1

        
End If
Next j
MsgBox "proceso Terminado; Total registros " & Totalregistros
IE.Quit ' cerramos el navegador
Set IE = Nothing ' limpia memoria
End Sub
```

Comment: Tuve un problema similar al actualizar a Windows 10. Resulta que 'Microsoft Internet Controls' y 'Microsoft HTML Object Library' se habían "eliminado" de "Referencias". Agregarlos resolvió el problema y el código funcionó bien sin requerir ninguna modificación. No sé si esto ayuda

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta; en mi caso esas referencias ya están. Lo que quisiera saber es si el código vba excel utilizado para trabajar con "Internet Explorer" sirve para trabajar con el explorador "EDGE"

Comment: Lamentablemente no, no existe librería para automatizat Edge mediante VBA. Dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer, pudiera ser que a lo mejor puedas extraer datos si son fuentes webs, apis, etc. Pero lo que es manipulación de formularios, navegar, etc no se puede

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta; era lo que necesitaba saber para entonces mirar otras opciones. Muy amable

Comment: lo que necesitas hacer se puede hacer con selenium, yo uso selenium basic para controlar Chrome